# Connecting Wattmeter in Proteus

Tags: power, simulation, proteus

I want to check the power across a device in Proteus. But I am unable to understand how to connect Wattmeter pins to the circuit. Please Help me to understand this or suggest any other method to calculate power.

**Thanks**

[image: Wattmeter]

Comment: Can you see pins that are for a voltage connection and pins that are for the current connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Wattmeter has a voltmeter and an ammeter. You need to connect the voltage coil across the load and current coil in series with the load.

If you double click on the wattmeter, it will show you options for seeing real/reactive/complex power.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot.

Comment: What's the other pin for?

Comment: what is the left out pin used for?

Comment: Never found out why 